# Text jumps while automatically resize textView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

if have a simple messageView in my app. on the messageView is a input-container with a textView. The textView should resize depending on its content.

It works so far, but every time while wrapping into the next line the text "jumps" for the first character, but reposition with the second character. it looks like:
[image]

[image]

[image]

the most of my code. i assume that it has something to do with the scroll capabilities of the textView(?)

```
private let container: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.90, green:0.90, blue:0.90, alpha:1.0).cgColor
    view.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return view
}()

private lazy var inputTV: UITextView = {
    let tv = UITextView()

    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tv.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Light", size: 16)
    tv.backgroundColor = .red
    tv.delegate = self
    tv.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

    return tv
}()

override internal init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    addSubview(container)
    container.addSubview(inputTV)

    container.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    container.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor , constant: 16).isActive = true
    container.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    containerHeightAnchor = container.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
    containerHeightAnchor?.isActive = true 

    inputTV.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uploadButton.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    inputTV.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    inputTV.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sendButton.leftAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    textViewHeightAnchor = inputTV.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.heightAnchor)
    textViewHeightAnchor?.isActive = true
}

internal func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let contentHeight = textView.contentSize.height
    containerHeightAnchor?.constant = max(contentHeight, 40)
    inputTV.frame.size.height = contentHeight
}
```

I hope somebody could help. regards

Comment: Try changing `let contentHeight = textView.contentSize.height` to `let contentHeight = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: textView.bounds.size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)).height`

Comment: Instead of trying to modify the Height Anchor... Don't give it a Height Anchor and disable scrolling. That will allow the text view to auto-size its height based on its text content.

Comment: @TheLivingForce i've tried to replace the contentHeight as you mentioned but it doesn't work. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @DonMag i do remove the `heightAnchor` from `textView`and it does work for me. The new code is as following:

- disable scrolling on the textView (`isScrollEnabled = false`)

  ```
  private lazy var inputTV: UITextView = {
      let tv = UITextView()

      tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      tv.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Light", size: 16)
      tv.delegate = self
      tv.isScrollEnabled = false

      return tv
  }()
  ```
- remove heightAnchor (**no** `inputTV.heightAnchor` resp. my `textViewHeightAnchor`)

  ```
  override internal init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

      translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

      addSubview(container)
      container.addSubview(inputTV)

      ...

      inputTV.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uploadButton.rightAnchor).isActive = true
      inputTV.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
      inputTV.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sendButton.leftAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
  }
  ```